# Creating an encrypted save file

Tags: ruby, encryption, loading, save

I'm trying to make a game in Ruby, and my latest addition is to save files, however, I'm having a major problem with encrypting them.

I already got the saving and loading methods set up, but I don't want to save them in plain-text, because that's begging for cheating. No matter what, the methods I use to try and store them encrypted, compressed, etc., all seem to spring some error on me.

What's the best method for saving text in a file? The only important thing is that the file can't be opened and edited.

Comment: "No matter what, the methods I use to try and store them encrypted, compressed, etc. all seem to spring some error on me". Post one of your attempts (using your preferred method) and the error you get, it will be easier to fix that than give you a general process for handling encryption, which is a large subject

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of people suggesting things, and then me going over why they don't work for me, with the hope of finding someone who either knew how to fix it or knew one that didn't break. I have tried a LOT of methods of handling this and not a single thing is working. I also gave up on it for a few months, so there's that.

Comment: That is the long way around to try to find a solution, and won't work well if you can't get sufficient suggestions. If you can't get people interested in your question you won't get the feedback you want. That's also not how Stack Overflow is supposed to work and would lead to votes that it isn't a real question.

Comment: Encrypting the file is not useful if they have the Ruby script at hand because they'll just change the script to save the data in plain text, then cheat. If you want to keep them from cheating you'll have to keep the source and the data out of reach. Also, if they can't open and edit the file, how is the code going to open the file when it needs to read it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [crypt gem](http://crypt.rubyforge.org/) to encrypt/decrypt your file.

But keep in mind that if your users can view your Ruby script, there's basically no way to hide your data, since any encryptions requires some kind of keys.

Comment: Most of the crypt algorithms don't work for me -- it's possible the code is outdated. For instance, using Blowtorch at all: C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/crypt-1.1.4/crypt/blowfish.rb:47:in `|': can
't convert String into Integer (TypeError)

Comment: Or, trying to use Rijndael: Ruby RPG failed gracefully: undefined method `length' for 65:Fixnum from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/crypt-1.1.4/crypt/stringxor.rb:9:in `^'. With all due respect, it's well-tread ground.

Comment: `can't convert String into Integer (TypeError) ` or `undefined method length' for 65:Fixnum` is hardly likely to be in the encryption code, but is a lot more likely to be as a result of your code not being written correctly. Unless you show us relevant pieces of code we can't help you.